# Output do_shortcode in JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

The `do_shortcode` is not replying me anything.

It should reply me the shortcode value, but when I use this same( only the PHP script) in PHP file it's replying me the value.

But while I'm pushing it in JavaScript variable then it is not replying me anything.

```
<script>
  function append2(){
     var video2;

     video2='<?php 
        $custom_fields = get_post_custom();
        $mykey_values = $custom_fields['wpcf-picture-movie-link']; 

        foreach ( $mykey_values as $key => $value ) {
            if($value!=''){ 
                do_shortcode($value) ; 
            } 
        } 
      ?> ';

    $("#hide_video2").append(video2);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: view the page source....

Comment: Always use `json_encode()` around any arbitrary data you want to use in the context of JavaScript.

Comment: can i have an example for it ?

Comment: I edited your code for clarity without touching the HTML output. Make sure you organize your code, it's better for you and for who wants to help. . . . For your problem, just [read the documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode) and see the ***Usage*** example.

Comment: @NayanenduMondal you should see http://goo.gl/wPM8ha. It might help your problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:-

```
<script>
  function append2(){
     var video2;

     video2='<?php 
        $custom_fields = get_post_custom();
        $mykey_values = $custom_fields['wpcf-picture-movie-link']; 

        foreach ( $mykey_values as $key => $value ) {
            if($value!=''){ 
                echo do_shortcode($value) ; // echo  the shortcode
            } 
        } 
      ?> ';

    $("#hide_video2").append(video2);
  }
</script>
```